# How to bind list of element value in html to Array of an object in Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript

Due to `[(ngModel)]`, you are able to bind value of an element in html to a field in component in angulare5.

**Problem statement**

There are a list of objects that are shown in a grid in html. like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let entity of objectList;">
    <td> <input type="text" value="entity.name"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="entity.code"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="entity.itemName"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <input type="submit" (click)="saveGroup()">
</tr>
```

and user wants to edit these value and saves in group by clicking on submit-button.

I want to declare an Array of this Object like this: `public objectList: Item[]` and bind to the value of this grid. Whenever user changes the any value of the above grid, its entry of the record in the `objectList` is changed automatically.

If it is not possible, i will write more code to get the value of this gird.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`[(ngModel)]`** among the fields so the input fields uses two way data binding so whenever you update the object in the objectList it will be automatically updated.

```
<tr *ngFor="let entity of objectList;">
    <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entity.name"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entity.code"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entity.itemName"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There is a problem . The grid is filled by an objectList with the null value of these input elements and user will fill these null values and save to another object. So 
    [(ngModel)]="entity.name" is not  correct.

Comment: I omit the same value between these Object in my question in this site

Comment: i am not sure about what you are talking about , produce a fiddle

Comment: Please take it easy and answer to this question: There are two objects. Both of them have same fields but one of them has some more fields. How create one of these objects with using value of other one